# Why lines/images draw only on last page of pdf using dompdf in php

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I am trying to draw line/image on every page of pdf using dompdf but it starts from second page, why this is so ? anyone has any idea ?
Here is my code

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($message2);
$dompdf->set_paper('a4','portrait');
$dompdf->render();

$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();

//For Header
$header = $canvas->open_object();
$canvas->image($header_image1,'jpg',0, 0, 595, 100);
$canvas->line(0,100,595,100,array(0,0,0),1);
$canvas->close_object();
$canvas->add_object($header, "all");

//For Footer
$footer = $canvas->open_object();
$canvas->line(0,740,650,740,array(0,0,0),1);
$canvas->image($footer_image1,'jpg',0, 742, 595, 100);
$canvas->close_object();
$canvas->add_object($footer, "all");

$output = $dompdf->output();
```

this code draw line/image on pdf but it only display on last page.
I have two pages in pdf and my line/images are drawn on second page not on first page.

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Adding objects in DomPDF works *from the current page onwards*. In other words, your objects will get added, but only from the page you currently have and then onwards to any new pages you add.

In your code, you've already converted your HTML to PDF, so the current page is more than likely the last page in your document. So your header / footer are added there, but not to any previous pages.

To place content on every page, domPDF provides two methods: `page_text` and `page_script`.

In your case the following type of code should do the trick:

```
$canvas->page_script('
  $pdf->line(10,730,800,730,array(0,0,0),1);
');
```

Code in the `page_script` function is then executed for *every* PDF page.

Comment: thanks for reply, I already tried this but not displays lines on any page. I also edit the file cpdf_adapter.cls.php file in include folder where the page_script function was missing I wrote it as follows 

    function page_script($code, $type = "text/php") {
    $_t = "script";
    $this->_page_text[] = compact("_t", "code", "type");
  }

Please help me if I missed anything here.

Comment: @SachinEndait You may need to update your copy of dompdf. v0.6.1 is recommended and should not require any editing of the source.

Comment: If you solved your issue, may I suggest you write an answer to that effect so that other people can be helped as well? That's how this site works...

Answer (score 1):

The line is not displayed for me because embedded php was disabled. 
This solved the problem:

```
$dompdf->set_option("isPhpEnabled", true);
```

This line has to be placed before $dompdf->render().

Answer (score 0):

how to add image in all pdf page using header and footer.below is my code.

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf');
$pdf->loadFile('invoice.html');
$pdf->output();
$dom_pdf = $pdf->getDomPDF();
$canvas = $dom_pdf ->get_canvas();
$image1="logo.png";
$canvas->image($image1,'png', 0, 0, 50, 25);
$canvas->page_text(10, 10, "Page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", null, 10, array(0, 0, 0));
$pdf->save('pdf_report/eft_payment-'.$RandomAccountNumber.'.pdf');
```